# How to calculate percentage on state change in react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

i am having the below state

```
const [data,setData] = useState({maths:null,physics:null,chem:null,percentage:null})
```

and i was updating the state as

```
setData({...data,[e.target.name]:e.target.value})
```

and my fuction for calculating the percentage is

```
function percentage(data.maths,data.physics,data.chem){ 
     const per = ((data.maths+data.physics+data.chem)/100)*100
return per
}
```

my doubt is when to call this function(like useEffect or like normal) and store it in data.percentage
please help me

Comment: I would do it in ```useEffect``` and make sure the dependency array is set to ```data```. And in your useEffect, add the result of the percentage function to your state

Comment: use useEffect and pass the array deps as data, so if any of the property changes it will run it which you want to do it

Comment: `useEffect(() => {
    const per = percentage((data.maths+data.physics+data.chem)
    setData({...data,percentage:per})
  },[data]);`   like this @DILEEPTHOMAS

Comment: Check this one https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-breeze-1ch9o, if it helped will update the answer

Comment: @AkshitaSri did you checked it

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS Lol, she's saying she want percentage in data state only but in my opinion it's not a good way of handling state. Rest is her choice.

Comment: thats why initially i have split that to a different variable, sure let it be her, choice adding the link on the answer

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS why cant we do like this https://codesandbox.io/s/great-neumann-yipil?file=/src/App.js  can u please explain the error was displaying in console.

Comment: i think the warning its is self explanatory isn't, you are updating the object by doing setState({...data, }) by this snippet so every time it creates a new object, and your array deps is data which will see okay new object i will again re-run the function inside useEffect, so goes to infinite loop

Answer (score 1):

Try doing the function in useState as shown below and as mentioned pass the state as the array deps, so whenever any of the property in the state changes it will recalculate, which is your required output.

or as Germa suggested you can skip the function itself and do it something like this

```
const [avg, setAvg] = useState(0)

useEffect(() => {
    const {
        maths,
        physics,
        chem
    } = data
    const per = ((data.maths + data.physics + data.chem) / 100) * 100
    setState(per)
}, [data])
```

I have added the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-breeze-1ch9o) based on the discussion, having it in diff state will be much more better way, or else when you pass the array deps it will keep on changing.

Comment: XD if inside `useEffect` then what's the point of using function also? Just skip it

Comment: then its throwing an error "Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render." @GermaVinsmoke

Comment: one sec let me check it

Comment: setAvg(per). Also why destructure data if you are not using those variables?

Comment: @AkshitaSri one question, when you click any button like calc avg only this function works or not ? i was adding the codesandbox can u help me here with the info what you are trying

Comment: no it should automatically caluculate them when ever the math physics or chem changes like if(math==null,physics==null.chem==null){return null}else{calulate per and setData({...data,percentage:per})

Comment: is these are input fields ?

Comment: haa yes math physics and chem are input fields percentage is p tag where we can display {data.percentage}

Comment: sure got it, will update the link here one min

Comment: @AkshitaSri where you able to understand this

Answer (score 0):

```js
function percentage(data){ 
     const per = ((data.maths+data.physics+data.chem)/100)*100
     return per
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const { maths, physics, chem } = data;
    const percentage = ((maths + physics + chem) / 100) * 100;
    setData({ maths, physics, chem, percentage });
  }, [data]);
```

the useEffect will run every time data changes, and data.percentage will be recalculated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, percentage should be divided by 300 I guess.
The percentage was a part of the same data as your input field so it was causing infinite loop whenever we were setting percentage in `useEffect`. So, it's better to separate the percentage from the input data of subjects.

[Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/calculate-subject-percentage-dm02y)

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({ maths: 0, physics: 0, chem: 0 });
  const [percentage, setPercentage] = useState(0);

  const fields = [
    { name: "maths", value: data.maths },
    { name: "physics", value: data.physics },
    { name: "chem", value: data.chem }
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    // Not sure but percentage should be divided 300 I guess
    const per = ((data.maths + data.physics + data.chem) / 300) * 100;
    setPercentage(per);
  }, [data]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setData({
      ...data,
      [e.target.name]: parseInt(e.target.value)
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Percentage: {percentage}</h1>
      {fields.map((field, idx) => (
        <input
          key={idx}
          placeholder={field.name}
          name={field.name}
          value={field.value}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: i need to store percentage in data state only

Comment: But there's a difference in between **need to** and what's a **better** option.